# personalizar scroll no fire fox e IE

Tags: jquery, css

Bom esse scroll funciona perfeitamente no chrome e safari. Queria saber como fazer a barra de rolagem igual no IE e Firefox.

Segue código.

```css
.container {
    height:200px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 250px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #dad7d7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content" style="height:600px;">pagina</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não concordo. Pois quero algo mais específico para firefox. A resposta desse tópico não responde a minha dúvida.

Comment: Como eu havia dito antes do fechamento, o fato de não ter a resposta que atende não justifica respostas em perguntas separadas. Você pode abrir um bônus naquela para tentar atrair alguma resposta mais completa. Fechamento por duplicata não é uma penalização, mas uma forma da sua pergunta indicar a outra, tanto para futuras consultas como para novas respostas.